# Processing serial port error

Tags: serial-port, arduino, processing

I'm trying to get my arduino to communicate with a processing program. Every time I do it I get this error:
`"Error opening serial port /dev/tty.usbmodem1441: Port busy"`. My arduino is using the same port.

Here is my processing code:

```
import processing.serial.*;

  Serial myPort;    
  String val;

void setup()
{

  String portName = Serial.list()[5];    
  myPort = new Serial(this, portName, 9600);
}

void draw()
{
    if ( myPort.available() > 0) {    
        val = myPort.readStringUntil('\n');
    }
    println(val);
}
```

I got it from https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/connecting-arduino-to-processing and I didn't change anything.

Comment: Just fyi: you can't have the Ardunio serial port monitor while trying t connect to the Arduino from Processing. (you don't mention if that is the case, but it is a common error).

Comment: Thanks a lot I did that and it worked!

Answer (score 3):

If you have the Arduino serial monitor open, attempting to connect to the serial line with Processing will create a conflict, resulting in that error. Simply close the serial monitor and try starting the sketch again. (Maybe reset Arduino too by clicking Reset button near AREF)

Answer (score 1):

Just close the "Serial Monitor" in Arduino and everything will work fine

Answer (score 0):

**You cant use same port for two diffrent purpose at a same time.**

check if that is the case. If thats not the case then try restarting arduino and pc both.

also make sure you are connected to the right port.

```
ls -l /dev/tty.*  should return all connected dvices if you are in unix system
```

if you are in window, may be its under device mager(its been long time i used window)